# How to always keep n elements of a collection?

Tags: c#, collections

What is the best way to keep n elements of a collection in c# ?

Remove old elements when adding a new one.

[image: keep n elements of a collection]

This is what I did:

```
List<int> listOf5Elements = new List<int>();
for(var i = 0; i<200; i++)
{
    listOf5Elements.Add(i);
    if (listOf5Elements.Count() == 6)
        listOf5Elements.RemoveAt(0);
}

LinkedList<int> linkedOf5elements = new LinkedList<int>();
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    linkedOf5elements.AddLast(i);
    if (linkedOf5elements.Count() == 6)
        linkedOf5elements.RemoveFirst();
}

Queue<int> queueOf5Elements = new Queue<int>();
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    queueOf5Elements.Enqueue(i);
    if (queueOf5Elements.Count() == 6)
        queueOf5Elements.Dequeue();
}
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: if you're mostly adding to the end and removing from the start then a `Queue` seems to make the most sense to me.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your opinion^^ Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: The most efficient way to do this is the circular buffer that GRAGIN mentioned, though there isn't a build in implementation.  So it really depends on exactly how you want to use the collection outside of the limit.  Specifically do you need to access different indexes.  Do you ever need to remove items from the middle of the collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). There are many implementations out there. [Here is one](http://www.geekswithblogs.net/blackrob/archive/2014/09/01/circular-buffer-in-c.aspx).

It's efficient in both time and space; in time because an insert is **O(1)** and in space because the new element overwrites the oldest in-place.

Your first attempt is not efficient because `RemoveAt(0)` is **O(n)** because the elements have to shift.

The second isn't too bad, but has some overhead in allocating the new slot, and deleting the old one.

The third attempt is the best because the .NET queue *is* impemented as a circular buffer, but there's some overhead dealing with resizing. Since you don't care about resizing, a true circular buffer with a fixed size would be a bit more efficient.